# Apache Rewrite and variable

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite:

http://url.com/app_name/action.do

to

http://url.com/context/action.do?value=1

My question is how to add the variable 'value' to the url for each rewrited URL (it's a hard coded value) ?

```
#RewriteRule ^/app_name(.*) /context$1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/app_name(/.*)?$ /context$1?value=1 [QSA]
```

The [*QSA* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) is to automatically append the original query to the new one.